# javascript push to array inside loop during mongoose query and save

Tags: javascript, json, mongoose, push

I don't know to structure the Javascript to return a list of updated json objects after performing a mongoose query and save.

Currently I'm trying something similar to the code below but with no luck.  The resBankMembers array is always empty.

Json from request body:

```
[
 {
   _id : (some id), 
   name = (some name)
 },  
 { _id : (some id), 
   name = (some name) 
 }
}
```

Code example (non working):

```
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(req.body);
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonText);
var resBankmembers = [];    

jsonObject.forEach(function(updatebankmember) {
    var bid = ObjectID(updatebankmember._id);
    BankMember.findOne({ "_id" : bid }, function(error,bankmember) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {  
            bankmember.name = updatebankmember.name;
            bankmember.save(function (error) {
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                else {
                    resBankmembers.push(bankmember);
                }
            });
        }               
    });
});
res.send(200, resBankmembers);
```

Please help!

Comment: Add a console to the save function. Console the variable `bankmember` and tell me what it is consoling.

Comment: Inside the save function's else block the bankmember is exactly what I want it to be ... { _id : (some object id), name : (some name) }.

Comment: I need to put in various consoles so you can see exactly what's happening. Add `console.log(resBankmembers)` after the push. See what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(req.body);
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonText);

jsonObject.forEach(function(updatebankmember, i) {
    var bid = ObjectID(updatebankmember._id);
    BankMember.findOne({ "_id" : bid }, function(error,bankmember) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {  
            bankmember.name = updatebankmember.name;
            bankmember.save(function (error) {
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                else {
                    jsonObject[i].id   = bankmember.id;
                    jsonObject[i].name = bankmember.name;
                }
            });
        }               
    });
});
res.send(200, jsonObject);
```

Instead of trying to push objects into an array, just update the already parsed `JSON`.

I also recommend using this for the `else` in the `save` function:

```
else {
     for (var key in bankmember) {
         jsonObject[i][key] = bankmember[key];
     }
}
```

In case you expand the bankmember object later on.

The `forEach` function isn't supported in IE 8 and Below so I recommend:

```
if (Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function (fun) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            fun.call(this, this[i], i)
        }
    };
}
```

Unless you don't want to support IE. I hope this helped.